# Avocado plant growing too tall, can I prune it without any leave growth

Tags: avocado

[image]

Can I cut this avocado plant back?  Almost 2 feet long and first of leaves just starting to grow.

Comment: It is looking for light. Give it more light, and it will growth less (and with more leaves).

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid not. Cutting the stem off below the leaves would bring an end to your plant. Perhaps it’s time to plant it in a pot. Avocado plants grow quite large so you’ll probably need to repot it regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have never done it with plant sitting in water, however I made it with my potted avocados and they all survived - moreover, thanks to such radical pruning they're now multi-stem plants and looking really good.